# Does LendingClub's quick screening impact credit score?

Tags: credit-score, credit-report, credit-history, lending-club

I'm new to the US and trying to get a loan for buying a car. I know it's hard to get a loan without credit history, but I just clicked around.

I typed some information from the homepage of LendingClub. After creating an account it also requires my SSN and I provided. Then it rejected my application.

What I want to know is if this had already impact my credit score (e.g., hard pull)?

Here's LeadningClub said to me:

> After very carefully reviewing your application, we are sorry to advise you that we cannot approve your loan request for the following reasons:
>
> - Unable to obtain credit report from bureau
> - Unable to verify identity
>
> The consumer reporting agency contacted that provided information that influenced our decision in whole or in part was:
>
> Transunion
>   P.O. Box 1000
>   Chester, PA 19022
>   1-800-888-4213
>   www.transunion.com
>
> We also obtained your credit score from this consumer reporting agency and used it in making our credit decision. Your credit score is a number that reflects the information in your credit report. Your credit score can change, depending on how the information in your credit report changes.
>
> - Your credit score:
> - Date of Credit Report Pull: Tuesday, Sep 1, 2015
> - Scores range from 300 to 850
> - Key factors that adversely affected your credit score:
>
> The reporting agency played no part in our decision and is unable to supply specific reasons why we have denied credit to you. You have a right under the Fair Credit Reporting Act to know the information contained in your credit file at the consumer reporting agency. You also have a right to a free copy of your report from the reporting agency, if you request it no later than 60 days after you receive this notice. In addition, if you find that any information contained in a report you receive is inaccurate or incomplete, you have the right to dispute the matter with the reporting agency. Any questions regarding such information should be directed to Transunion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you filled out the [Check Your Rate](https://www.lendingclub.com/borrowerc/personalInfo.action?loanAmount=%245000&loanPurpose=major_purchase&creditScore=EXCELLENT&rate-submit=Check+Your+Rate) page, then Lending Club is doing a [soft pull](https://www.creditkarma.com/article/hard_inquiries_and_soft_inquiries), according to that page.  That means they're checking your score, but not doing anything that would normally show up on a credit pull.  See the button you select:

[image: Button with won't impact credit score]

Further, if they were unable to obtain said report at all, it can't affect your credit in any way - since the credit profile doesn't exist yet!

Comment: But after the page, it ask me to submit my SSN to get a "custom rate". I forget if there's a "won't impact your credit score" note on the button.

Comment: They'd need your SSN to get even a soft pull.

Comment: But it also said "You also have a right to a free copy of your report from the reporting agency", doesn't it means they already used a hard pull, or soft pull may also grant me the right to ask for a free copy from TU?

Comment: I am not a lawyer or a specialist in this particular area, but a naive reading of the requirement is that they'd have to provide you with that if even a soft pull caused them to reject you.  (e.g. [the FTC's page on your FCRA rights](https://www.consumer.ftc.gov/articles/pdf-0096-fair-credit-reporting-act.pdf).)

Comment: Thanks for your answer especially for providing the link!